# Add button in every list Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i add button delete in every list that i create in picking list with the toogle off in the button, and button remove the list item. thanks

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Input the items</p>
<input id="userinput" class="search" type="text" placeholder="enter items" onkeydown="teston()">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myFunction(){
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id","myLi");

    var teks = document.createTextNode(input.value);

    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(teks);

    input.value="";
  } 
}

function lineThrough() {
  event.target.classList.toggle('done');
}

buttonEnter.addEventListener("click",myFunction);
myUL.addEventListener("click", lineThrough);
```

**CSS:**

```
.done {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question, it isn't clear what problem you have.

Comment: i need the button in every <li> tags, so i can remove the list that i want

Comment: So do you need help to create the button, or the function to delete the current `<li>` tag?

Comment: ya, help me please, i'm new learn code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use `document.createElement` to create a button, then add an event listener that listens for clicks and then calls a delete function of your own creation with `.addEventListener` like so:

```
function myFunction(){
  if(inputLength() > 0){
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id","myLi");
    var teks = document.createTextNode(input.value);

    // New code here:
    const myUL = document.getElementById("myUL")

    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
    deleteButton.innerText = 'Delete'

    // listens for clicks and then deletes the `li`
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', event => myUL.removeChild(li))
    // End of new code

    li.appendChild(deleteButton)
    myUL.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(teks);
    input.value="";
  }
}
```

Comment: i get error " li is not defined " , what should i do?create the variable li ?

Comment: And when did the `li is not defined` error occur, at runtime or after clicking the button?

Comment: Oh, your problem is you put the code in the wrong place, it's supposed to be in `myFunction`.